SSE react '406 (Not Acceptable)'
I have some problem with react and django application.
I want to use SSE to let the two of them communicate, but I get 406 responses from the front end.
I think I fail when I try to connect.
I can't get a response from the backend.
This is my django code
class Test(viewsets.ViewSet):
  
    def list(self, request):
        def test():
            i = 1
            while i < 6:
                yield f'data: {i}\n\n'
                i += 1


        return StreamingHttpResponse(test(), content_type='text/event-stream')

And my react code
import { NativeEventSource, EventSourcePolyfill } from 'event-source-polyfill';

export default function Teset() {
    const test = () => {
        const EventSource = EventSourcePolyfill;

        const eventSource = new EventSource(
            "http://localhost:30018/test/",
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
              },
              withCredentials: true,
            }
          );
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={test}>button</button>
        </>
    )
}

If you know the answer, please leave an answer.
I saw an answer on Google saying you just need to specify what type you will receive in the header, but to no avail.
